Distribution of distribution function $F(X)$
In the book Probability and Measure I found the following exercise:

14.3 (a) Suppose that $X$ has a continuous, strictly increasing distribution function
$F$. Show that the random variable $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed over the unit
interval in the sense that $P[F(X) < u] = u$ for $0 < u < 1$. Passing from $X$ to
$F(X)$ is called the probability transformation.

I just dont know where to start with this. Can anyone help me with some intuition for what 'the distribution of random variable $F(X)$' means? Then I can take it from there. Thanks in advance

Do you know what "the distribution of $X^2$" means? Or "the distribution of $2X+1$"? Or "the distribution of $e^X$"? This is another similar case - you have some function $F$ (which happens to have some special properties to do with the distribution of $X$, but never mind that for the moment), and you are asked about the distribution of $F(X)$. If you wanted to know about the distribution of $X^2$, you might consider $P[X^2\leq u]$ for each $u$. Here you want to know about the distribution of $F(X)$, so you look at $P[F(X)\leq u]$ for each $u$.

This question is a duplicate of: Finding the distribution function for the random variable $F(X)$..

The entity $F(X)$ is the distribution function $F$ applied to the random variable $X$. For example, if $X$ has exponential distribution with rate $\alpha$, its distribution function is, for $x\ge0$,
$$F(x):=P(X\le x)=1 - e^{-\alpha x}.$$
So for this $X$ you are being asked to find the distribution of the random variable $1-e^{-\alpha X}$ when $X$ has exponential($\alpha$) distribution.
As a simpler example, if $X$ has uniform distribution over the interval $[0,a]$, its distribution function is, for $x\in[0,a]$,
$$F(x):=P(X\le x)=x/a.$$ The random variable $F(X)$ in this case is $X/a$. You're being asked to find the distribution of $X/a$, which you can quickly see is uniform$[0,1]$.
